# Trying to access terminal remotely, and being able to resume it. What are my options?

Tags: ssh, terminal

I have a machine that is running CentOs 7.7. I'm trying to access the terminal remotely, and execute a script. Right now I use putty to connect to server via SSH, and type `./run_server.sh` to execute my script. The content of the `run_server.sh` file is as follows (extremely simplified):

```
#!/bin/bash
run_script=(./my_calculator_server)
"${run_script[@]}"
```

It then starts to execute my calculator server, which can accept two numbers and output their sum (again simplified). The problem is, if I close the Putty program, the script is terminated, so is the session. Even if the script is not terminated, I won't be able to go back to it since running Putty again will open a fresh terminal window. I want to be able to remotely access that session, interact with it and go back to it anytime I want. Is it possible? If so, what are my options?

I'm not asking for step-by-step instructions, only looking to find the ways to do this.

PS: VNC is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that the process is a child process of your current shell session. When your shell closes, all child processes get terminated. You need to disown the process from the current shell:

I know of these three options:

---

`disown`:

Run your command, then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the current process, run `bg` to let it continue in background and then run `disown`.

---

Use `nohup` if you need an easy way to get the output logged:

```
nohup your_command &
```

Find the output of your command in a file named `nohoup.out` by default.

---

Use a `screen` or `tmux` session if you need to reattach to your process.

---

Similar questions:

- [Keep processes running after SSH session disconnects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-processes-running-after-ssh-session-disconnects)
- [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Although I've already tried the first two. I wasn't able to go back to that session. I'm reading about `tmux` right now, if it supports resuming the session, it's just what I needed.

Comment: I use `screen` for that. Never used `tmux` ;-)