# How best to start a background resource intensive task in bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running some long running tasks (15 minutes up to a day) in Ubuntu 18.04 under WSL2, itself under Win11.

A couple of times my terminal has stopped responding and never came back, but I could see from resource usage that the task was still running.

How can I best start this task so it's a background task that will persist even if my interactive session ends prematurely?

Important requirements are:

- The task must be running in the background
- I should be able to
  reconnect to the session if something happens to it
- Output should be
  logged somewhere in case I don't reconnect in time
- The task is
  resource intensive, so the method of starting it should not decrease
  performance substantially
- Ideally I should be able to do all of the above locally as well as over SSH

Just in case it's important, the actual task is a tensorflow job running  under python 3.9, within an anaconda environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep processes running after SSH session disconnects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-processes-running-after-ssh-session-disconnects) or [How can I run a command which will survive terminal close?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-run-a-command-which-will-survive-terminal-close)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run a command which will survive terminal close?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-run-a-command-which-will-survive-terminal-close)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `screen` for that.

You can simply reconnect to a session if the connection gets lost via `screen -r`.

Sending the task to background as well as logging can additionally be done with `&` and `>>` if necessary.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!